# How to download entire directory in sftp using libcurl

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl, sftp

I am programing in C. I want to download a particular directory from server (SFTP) using libcurl. I know we can download a file using the following option but how to download a directory. For SFTP wildcardmatch option is also not supported so that I can download all the files in that directory atleast.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fd);
```

Platform: Linux

Comment: Have you solved this issue?? I am facing same problem.

Comment: Yes, i have listed the files from the SFTP server and select the desired files . And then downloaded one by one. In this way only we can achieve this. There is no callback option in libcurl to directly achieve this.

Comment: @john could you please help out as to how you solved the problem as I am very new to programming and running into the same issue, I can download only 1 file using examples form the curl site. Example source would be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to explicitly list the directory, and download every file inside which is not `.` or `..`  (possibly recursing on sub directories).

So you issue first a request to list the directory. Then you build (locally) an array of entries obtained by that request. Then, for each such entry, you issue a request to download the file, or, if it is a [sub-]directory, you recurse inside.

And you always would have issues if another client of your FTP server would add or delete files in that same directory.

BTW, some FTP servers are able to e.g. archive an entire directory `foo/` if you retrieve `foo.tar.gz` etc..

Comment: Is there any option in libcurl ?

Comment: Ya , namit i have implemented this.

Comment: Can you please describe your solution?